# How to replace context type definition for the function

Tags: typescript, this, typescript-generics

I'm trying to create a configuration function for executing set of functions with a predefined context.
Here are my types:

```
type Config<T> = {
    context: T;
};

type Hooks<T> = {
    hooks: T;
};

type FunctionWithThis<T> = (this: T, ...args) => any;
```

In my configure function I want to merge context and my target functions, but pass context parameter as `this` to functions:

```
 const configure = <TContext extends Object, 
                    THooks extends Record<string, FunctionWithThis<TContext>>>
                   (config: Config<TContext> & Hooks<THooks>) => {
    const result = {
        get data() { return config.context; }
    };

    Object.entries(config.hooks).forEach((action) => {
        result[action[0]] = (...args) => action[1].call(config.context, ...args);
    });

    return result as { data: TContext; } & THooks;
};
```

It can be used like this:

```
const engine = configure({
    context: {
        foo: 12
    },
    hooks: {
        log() {
            console.log(this.foo); // this.foo is typed correctly here
        }
    }
});

const data = engine.data;
engine.log(); // error here
```

VS Code gives me following error in the last line:

> The 'this' context of type '{ data: { foo: number; }; } & { log(this:
> { foo: number; }): void; }' is not assignable to method's 'this' of
> type '{ foo: number; }'.   Property 'foo' is missing in type '{ data:
> { foo: number; }; } & { log(this: { foo: number; }): void; }' but
> required in type '{ foo: number; }'.

I believe that it means that I'm trying to call `log` function in the wrong context.
Is it possible to change context type for each function in the output?

Or maybe there is another way to solve it?

[Typescript Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBAwg9gOwGYEsDmAeAKgPigXigG8BYAKCkqgGNFgIAPYALiiwG5yBfTs80SFAAScOAGsAztjyFSFKgAtRk1h269+4aADEArgmrAUiAOopgCrApRTcBKAAoLN1QBooAOi8BDAE5oJVm8EEABtAF0ASgI8YJANPjJaBAlgGkRUNF1faEJseAR6JihGegQAEwkoAHkAIwArCENXcio2EXEq0ogKqoAlJrhfcoxU3xQENHc9AyNTc0trWwKi4Bx11qoHZMzWAsz8ulK8ADJhZVsOyRxo-Dw5Tcpk1KgciV0AGzTZR7aoNAgaXK3mA3gc0SIr0B2QQ6WQ6A8yVW7CgXF+XCg3iqcQSbTqjUMHh6wHGEAk2wyCKUnUiHiQQwAot5qAoHA5mXMELd7r82m9PsBQhzjAhQgAGcLhewOLwePwBIIhCLczGGEWhACM4UR3g+Hwp8LQiKOTHcsvlEkivDaXCt5F+OWAMKh7y+mKqkOBoNUK1KKIxZywVwkvB49sSzzSPTQE1ycMy2QgDjkbSRpVYKb+lHpcFYGoATOiWvJKNSVMReVQPnA0OCKyWs1RnnAPhAPNXa84JHTRFaoAB6ftQLs9uBQGzDrTldK+HKGD4gKAKCA5SuUNENje2hKRqBe7z2aOxjz73iDo8INsd8EowclWdDJcriBAA)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since `THooks` must have members of type `(this: T, ...args: any[]) => any`, the functions on `THooks` will require `this` to be of type `TContext`. And while your function does ensure the `this` will indeed be of `TContext`, the types of the retuned functions don't reflect this. So when calling one of these functions on `engine`, ts looks at the type of `enigine` and sees it is not the appropriate `this` for `log` and issues an error.

Since you pass in `this` inside your implementation, you need to erase the `this` parameter from the result. You can do this with a mapped conditional type:

```
type Config<T> = {
    context: T;
};

type Hooks<T> = {
    hooks: T;
};

type FunctionWithThis<T> = (this: T, ...args: any[]) => any;

type RemoveThis<T extends Record<string, FunctionWithThis<any>>> = {
    [P in keyof T]: T[P] extends (...a: infer A) => infer R ?  (...a:A) => R: never
}

 const configure = <TContext extends Object, 
                    THooks extends Record<string, FunctionWithThis<TContext>>>
                   (config: Config<TContext> & Hooks<THooks>) => {
    const result = {
        get data() { return config.context; }
    };

    Object.entries(config.hooks).forEach((action) => {
        (result as any)[action[0]] = (...args: any[]) => action[1].call(config.context, ...args);
    });

    return result as { data: TContext; } & RemoveThis<THooks>;
};

const engine = configure({
    context: {
        foo: 12
    },
    hooks: {
        log() {
            console.log(this.foo); // this.foo is typed correctly here
        }
    }
});

const data = engine.data;
engine.log(); // ok
```

[Playground Link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBAwg9gOwGYEsDmAeAKgPigXigG8BYAKCkqgGNFgIAPYALiiwG5yBfTs80SFAAScOAGsAztjyFSFKgAtRk1h269+4aADEArgmrAUiAOopgCrApRTcBKAAoLN1QBooAOi8BDAE5oJVm8EEABtAF0ASgI8YJANMgFoACUIAFs4ADcIKxtsKEZ6BAATCShU2l9ijAlgXxQENHc9AyNTc0trKTicXvs5KihQgAUoBqgxCBA4JDZw1RHwgqYIErKHLw9vVgakCF8oAEFo-Dxd-fKoAH5KDZ9mY5jy1gQIbN9ucnIaRFqf5HQul80EI2HgCHoTGWRVKUAA8gAjABWEEM7m+g0xWMGWBE4jKhVWsIqcCqNTqDSaUBahmMCDMFlytnBkOAvRwGOxXNutABaFY4NQmCwLMKeAAZMJlLY8ZIcCc8AMqLy-sCJLoADbAfqczFoCDa4reYDeBzRIhQYHAIEIf5Cjy81nsKBcXU8L7ySiIlGGDyrCkQCQOXn2pT4yIeJCkgCi3moCgcDjjbQQCuIusGDjVmu13jKcUioWTdNCAAZwktCHctv5AlA4hE08XEKEAIzhB3eDUa4OIe2OwruTZ+AKRXiDLhjj2DK02y2BnP1soWo0m1SipjOrhQSWpDLZJnYWUSHC8d18Mgq7WrNANEF2wHAhxKygDpisF+YqNwVitgBMbquLqYYqOmnqYhqcBoGaYHcsqvxwBqEAeJB0HOBIkaiGOUAAPQ4VA6GYXAYxlEkxQ-L4wKGBqIBQAo+wQBmVCuuBLGTgkV5QKu3j2Ded4eNxvB8a8KFQWazp4VA4hAA)